# How to update parent field with child field value FOR EXISTING records

Tags: field-update, master-detail, child-to-parent

There are two Objects with master-detail relationship (Contact and Certification__c)

I need to copy a textfield(Name) value from the child object(Certification__c) and paste it on it's Parent's(Contact) textfield(Certification_Token), for every contact which has a certification instance. Please note that this is for existing record values.

code:

```
List<Certification__c> CertificationObjects = new List<Certification__c>();
CertificationObjects = [SELECT Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__r.Certification_Token__c FROM Certification__c];

for(Certification__c c : CertificationObjects){
    if(c.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c == NULL){
        c.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c = c.Name;
    }
}
update CertificationObjects;
```

When I run this on the Execute Anonymous Window, it shows no error, but it is not updating it's parent. Should i map the fields using the Id and update it or can we fix this code? I do not require a workflow, as I need to update the existing values in the system, and not the future ones.

@UPDATE
not every contact instance will have a certification instance. A contact can have multiple certification instances, but all the certification instances of a particular contact can have only one .Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` DML command on the `CertificationObjects` will not update the Contact lookup fields' data - it only updates fields on the `Certification__c` record itself.

Try the following (*EDIT* - using Map to avoid duplicate Contact Id updates):

```
List<Certification__c> CertificationObjects = new List<Certification__c>();
CertificationObjects = [SELECT Name, Contact__r.Id, Contact__r.Certification_Token__c FROM Certification__c];

Map<Id, Contact> toUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();

for (Certification__c cert : CertificationObjects){
    if (String.isBlank(cert.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c)){
        toUpdate.put(cert.Contact__c, new Contact(Id = cert.Contact__c, Certification_Token__c = cert.Name));
    }
}
update toUpdate.values();
```

Comment: not every contact instance will have a certification instance. A contact can have multiple certification instances, but all the certification instances of a particular contact can have only one .Name. How would this affect the code? @Brian_Miller

Comment: Since you're querying `Certification__c`, you'll only be checking real Certification records.  I think everything is okay here

Comment: Line: 11, Column: 1
System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 0035C00000FRacdQAD . Line 11 is update toUpdate; I have updated my question with the new code

Comment: Ah, I hear.  See the updated answer that uses a `Map<Id, Contact>`.  Note that the certification token name will not represent every certification that the contact has, since `Map.put()` on the same Contact Id is just overwriting the value when the same contact shows up more than once.

Comment: that did the trick, thank a lot. Hope it doesn't affect existing values

Comment: Since we were looking for blank `Certification_Token__c`, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Would you be kind to explain this line 'new Contact(Id = cert.Contact__c, Certification_Token__c = cert.Name)' why does it say **new** Contact, will this create new records? or is it just that we are calling an instance of this object? please help

Comment: @NivethKumar `new Contact()` just creates an instance of the record in memory.  Since we're setting the Id, we're basically saying "this contact already exists", and now any other fields I put in this record will overwrite whatever is actually in the database when we do the `update` command.  Note that if we tried to do `insert` we would get an error because we set the `Id` field.

Comment: Understood, thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

please try this -

if(c.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c == NULL || c.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c =='')

Comment: this is not the issue here, I believe it's what Brain Miller has said.

Comment: `String.isBlank(c.Contact__r.Certification_Token__c)` should be used instead - it handles both null and empty string checks